# How to filter number from specified label format?

Tags: regex

I have a lot of strings containing custom tags:

```
hello {RT|12} world {RT|465} this is {RT|13243}a string with{RT|13}examples
```

I need a regex to filter out all numbers of tags of the form {RT|xx} with xx being a number of any possible length. Since I'm not that good with regex, I've been trying the following:

```
preg_match("/{RT|.*}/", $string, $matches)
```

This is now filtering out the {RT|xx}-tags, but what I need for $matches to hold is an araay(12, 456, 13243, 13). Who can help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Qtax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107152/qtax) I can't comment in your answer cause I don't have enough rep, but I'd say he should scape the pipe, so the regex match exactly the piece of text that he wants

```
preg_match_all('/{RT\|(\d+)}/', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER)
```

**Edit after poster comment on [@Qtax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107152/qtax) answer:**
[@reveller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330271/reveller) change your regex as I posted, you have a empty string cause you're matching the '{RT' before the | and the '(\d+)}' after the pipe, and since the first match don't have a group to catch up the value it return a empty string.

Changing as I posted you'll match the entire text so you'll get it only once and will have the numbers that you need.

Its happening cause a pipe '|' on regex means OR, so you're matching a '{RT' OR '(\d+)}'.
To not match it twice you need to escape the pipe so the regex will match it as text.

[This site](http://regexpal.com) is a good place to test your regexes, you just put the text you want to test, your regex on another one and you can easily see it working.

Comment: Thanks man, I accepted your answer...it should give you a start on your karma ;-)

Comment: Hehe, thanks but not needed to, only if I really helped, I'm just new to StackOverflow
:D

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
preg_match_all('/{RT\|(\d+)}/', $string, $matches)
```

And you desired values will be in `$matches[1]`.

Comment: Thanks, but why does $matches[1] also contain empty values?

Comment: @Reveller, missed to escape the `|`, fixed.